# an notAdirectoryerror in python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, face-recognition

i am making a face recognition program but i am facing NotADirectoryError error whenever i run it
i tried coping the full directory as well as using os.join.path and nothing worked
i am using pycharm.

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import os
import numpy
os.chdir('C:/Users/a/Desktop/ftp')



KNOWN_FACE_DIR = "known_faces"
print(KNOWN_FACE_DIR)
#UNKNOWN_FACES_DIR = r"unknown_faces"
TOLERANCE = 0.6
FRANE_THICKNESS = 3
FONT_THICKNESS = 2
MODEL = "cnn"

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


print("loading known faces ")

known_faces = []
known_names = []


for name in os.listdir(KNOWN_FACE_DIR):
    for filename in os.listdir(f"{KNOWN_FACE_DIR}/{name}"):
        image = face_recognition.load_image_file(f"{KNOWN_FACE_DIR}/{name}/{filename}")


print("processing unknown faces")
while True :
    #print(filename)
    #image = face_recognition.load_image_file(f"{UNKNOWN_FACES_DIR}/{filename}")
    ret ,image = video.read()

    locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image, model=MODEL)
    encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image, locations)
    #image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    for face_encoding, face_location in zip(encodings, locations):
        results = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_faces, face_encoding, TOLERANCE)
        match = None
        if True in results:
            match = known_names[results.index(True)]
            print(f"Match found:{match}")

            top_left = (face_location[3], face_location[0])
            bottom_right = (face_location[1], face_location[2])

            color = [0,255,0]

            cv2.rectangle(image, top_left, bottom_right, color, FRANE_THICKNESS)

            top_left = (face_location[3], face_location[2])
            bottom_right = (face_location[1], face_location[2]+22)

            cv2.rectangle(image, top_left, bottom_right, color, cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.putText(image, match, (face_location[3]+10,face_location[2]+15).cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.5,(200,200,200),FONT_THICKNESS)

    cv2.imshow(filename,image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
    cv2.destroyWindow(filename)
```

the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\a\Desktop\ftp\face recognition.py", line 27, in <module>
    for filename in os.listdir(f"{KNOWN_FACE_DIR}/{name}"):
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'known_faces/Majd.jpg'
```

i tried coping the whole directory
and using os.join.path although i am now sure i used it correctly

Answer (score 1):

The `os.listdir` function requires a *directory* name, and something called `Madj.jpg` is most likely to be a JPEG *file* rather than a directory.

It *looks* like your assumption that everything in `C:/Users/a/Desktop/ftp/known_faces` is a directory containing files that you want to process may not be correct.

Comment: I know that the directory should not point to a certain file but i am following a tutorial on youtube for sedtex and he did exactly the same and it worked here is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdkPI92KSIs&ab_channel=sentdex    If you have any possible fixes please share it with me @paxidiablo